# Redirect to other page in magento2 not working

Tags: magento2

i have create observer but the below code not working any solution?
$observer->getControllerAction()
->getResponse()
->setRedirect($url);

Comment: which event do you have used?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
    protected $redirect;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $url = "";//your redirect path
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), $url);

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: not working this solution

Comment: please share your code and observer event

Answer (score 0):

A custom rewrite can be used to manage miscellaneous redirects,but should not redirect at observer, You can do it at override